# C# : how to understand the result of this memory dump

Tags: c#, mef

We have made a dump of a c# (.Net fmk 4.5.1) that is using to much memory.
We suspect a memory leak, and all the memory seems to be held by the usage of MEF.

Here is the object (ContractService.ContratSingletonMgr) which is holding the more memory:

```
1c0eeeec 728ee2db System.Net.TimerThread.ThreadProc()
    ebp+50: 1c0eeef0 (interior)
        ->  11bfc4e0 System.Object[]
        ->  05c1cbc0 System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionContainer
        ->  05d92c78 System.EventHandler`1[[System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportsChangeEventArgs, System.ComponentModel.Composition]]
        ->  05d92c58 System.Object[]
        ->  05c1d04c System.EventHandler`1[[System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportsChangeEventArgs, System.ComponentModel.Composition]]
        ->  05c1cce4 System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider
        ->  05c1cdbc System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[[System.IDisposable, mscorlib]]
        ->  93011010 System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1+Slot[[System.IDisposable, mscorlib]][]
        ->  049f86a4 System.ComponentModel.Composition.ReflectionModel.DisposableReflectionComposablePart
        ->  049f86fc ContractService.ContratSingletonMgr
```

I do not understand how to fix the problem: I think I have to unsubscribe the CompositionContainer ExportsChangeEvent; but I have double checked my code and I do not have any subscription to this event...

As for the System.Net.TimerThread.ThreadProc: does that mean that the code is causing a memory leak while using a timer object?

Comment: Title gave me a giggle...

Comment: @maccettura and I thought Friday afternoons couldn't be better... :-)

Comment: @Dypso, in addition to the diagnostic stack, could you also show relevant parts of the user code related to the problem?

Comment: @dlatikai : the problem is I am trying to find this relevant code... I have make a dump and try to find the root cause of the memory consumption and this  ContractService.ContratSingletonMgr seem to hold the majority of it... BTW sorry for the bad english ;-)

Comment: An event in CatalogExportProvider is not being unregistered.

Comment: for acheologists, the titl used to be  '...result of my dump'